# Index of a dictionary value

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, dictionary, indexing

In the code below i am trying to access the indeces of a dictionary value in the MinimunSkew function below. If the dictionary is stored in variable s and i'm iterating over the values to find all indices of variable m, the following code only gives me the first index and not the second etc:

for i in s.values():
        positions = s.values().index(m)

How do i get all indices in dictionary of the value of variable m?

Full code:
    Genome="TAAAGACTGCCGAGAGGCCAACACGAGTGCTAGAACGAGGGGCGTAAACGCGGGTCCGAT"

```
def Skew(Genome):
skew = {}
n = len(Genome)
skew[0]=0
for i in range(1,n+1):
    skew[i] = skew[i-1]
    if Genome[i-1] == "G":
        skew[i] = skew[i-1]+1
    elif Genome[i-1] == "C":
        skew[i] = skew[i-1]-1  
    else:
        skew[i]=skew[i-1]
return skew
Skew(Genome)


def MinimumSkew(Genome):
positions=[]
s = Skew(Genome)
m = min(s.values())

for i in s.values():
    positions = s.values().index(m)

return positions
print MinimumSkew(Genome)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop of MinimumSkew not return position because dictionary has no index attribute. min(s.values()) returns only the lowest value of the dict. You need to modify your code. Here is modified version:

```
 def MinimumSkew(Genome):
            positions =[]
            s = Skew(Genome)
            minimumValue = min(s.values())

            for (k,v) in s.items():
                if v == minimumValue:
                    positions.append(k)
            return positions

 Genome = "GCATGCTTCGCATATGCTTGAACAACG"
 print(MinimumSkew(Genome))
```

Output:[26]